# CSS Selector Best Practice

Tags: css

When writing CSS, is there any reason to prefer shorter, more elegant selectors over longer, more comprehensible ones?  I'm looking for technical, not personnel, reasons – processor hits and whatnot.  There are often many ways to select the same element(s), and I'm unclear what, if anything, might be best practice.

Comment: Questions related to [HTML, JavaScript, or CSS coding](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are best asked on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) where there are more programmers that answer questions.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at the Block Element Modifier methodology http://getbem.com/

> No matter what methodology you choose to use in your projects, you
>   will benefit from the advantages of more structured CSS and UI. Some
>   styles are less strict and more flexible, while others are easier to
>   understand and adapt in a team.

Comment: Actually...I just found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44629754/best-practice-on-naming-css-class-selector-for-a-same-tag-but-different-behavio